# Does Linux network device have its own queue to hold incoming and outgoing packets?

Tags: networking

I am trying to understand how Linux handles packets for ingress and egress through any device.

Taking a simple example of a veth pair (say veth1 and veth2), when a packet is sent via veth1, it will be received at veth2. Now veth has its own kernel module and for transmitting through veth1, kernel will invoke its xmit() [function](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.8.17/source/drivers/net/veth.c#L122) where it will forward the packet to veth2.

Looking at the code for `dev_forward_skb()` and the invoked call to `netif_rx_internal()` [function](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.8/source/net/core/dev.c#L3786), as far as memory being used to hold the packet, the only role I see the device veth2 playing is to tell which CPU's queue the packet should be placed in (via `enqueue_to_backlog()` for further processing. The `process_backlog()` function goes on send packet to the network stack.

My question is this: does the device veth2 hold any queue of its own where it actually holds the packet (for ingress or egress), or does the device simply tell which CPU to use ? I see the [structure](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.8/source/include/linux/netdevice.h#L692) `netdev_rx_queue`, but I only find code so far that uses its map and flow table members.

The question extends to other devices like loopback, tun/tap and eth as well

Comment: https://www.coverfire.com/articles/queueing-in-the-linux-network-stack/